# What is causing content types to not display created nodes

Tags: nodes

I have an issue with a D7 site built in Panopoly. I have created several content types. When a user creates a node via one of these content types the node is blank. However the data is available (appears in the appropriate fields) if you click the "edit" tab.

The title of the node will be shown, but none of the other fields.

Comment: Change you theme to bartik also add a screenshot .

Comment: Switched to bartik. Same problem.

http://imgur.com/a/KLfgZ